# Sardine Webdav : How to create a new file?

Tags: java, android, webdav, sardine

I'm working on Webdav client Sardine. I'm unable to create a new file (ex: file.txt) on server using Sardine webclient for Webdav. I created the directory using

```
sardine.createDirectory(dirPathToCreate);
```

Is there any way to create a new file using Sardine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Sardine.put]
https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide

Comment: Hi Jawi.Frstly,Thanks for reply. Sardine.put("directoryPath/nameOfFile.jpg", fis)) asks for the fully qualified path.The thing is i am having a directory  'directoryPath' but not having the file (nameOfFile.jpg) in it.I have to create a new file with name nameofFile.jpg in directory 'directoryPath'.Is it possible?

Comment: It works according to the HTTP PUT method, which will create a new resource if needed. So doing a Sarding.put("/path/to/myFile.jpg") will create the "/path/to/myFile.jpg" file if needed, or replace it if it already exists...

Comment: Thanks a lot jawi.But i came 2 know for android, Sadine is not the best Webdav client due to dependencies.